# Length of loop - time control - C

Tags: c, linux, time

I am trying to control the length of execution of an application with the help of timer counter.
I see that the `time.h` does the job.

```
#include <time.h>

#define SIZE 256
void main(){
        time_t curtime,endtime;
        struct tm *loctime, *etime;
        char buffer[SIZE];

        //TIME
        curtime = time(NULL);
        endtime = curtime + 2*60;
        loctime = localtime (&curtime);
        etime = localtime (&endtime);
        strftime (buffer, SIZE, "The time is %S \n", loctime);
        fputs (buffer, stdout);
        strftime (buffer, SIZE, "The time is %S.\n", etime);
        fputs (buffer, stdout);
}
```

Why do I get the start and end time to be the same.

Comment: But I am incrementing the endtime by 120seconds.

Comment: You aren't doing anything to control the length of the of execution - no sleep etc in there at all...

Comment: But incrementing should atleast give the difference in elapsed times, right?

Comment: why? what do you think your code is doing? It is just putting the local time into the buffer. If you want to time something you need a timestamp before and after. What are ypu actually trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From man page of `localtime()` : The return value points to a **statically allocated struct which might be overwritten by subsequent calls to any of the date and time functions**.

You have two options,

1. After the first call to `localtime()`, copy the return value to another local variable and call it second time.
2. Use `localtime_r()` instead. *(Preferred)*

Man page of [localtime and localtime_r](http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime).

Comment: It says too few arguments to function `localtime_r`

Comment: The linked man page contains `localtime_r` function prototype which is `struct tm *localtime_r(const time_t *timep, struct tm *result);`. So send the address of valid `struct tm` as second parameter. Example : http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.iseries.langref.doc/rzan5mst156.htm

Comment: time_t curtime,endtime;
struct tm *loctime, *etime, newtime;

loctime = localtime (&curtime);
etime = localtime_r (&endtime,&newtime);

Am I correct now?

Comment: @user2015933, check this link for complete working code. http://codepad.org/SAu8MAo1

Answer (score 0):

You should use `localtime_r` instead of `localtime` to get the two different times.

From `man localtime`:

> The return  value  points  to  a statically allocated struct which might be
>          overwritten by subsequent calls to any of the date and time  functions.
>          The  localtime_r()  function  does  the  same, but stores the data in a
>          user-supplied struct.